# Verification process for google picker

Tags: google-oauth, google-picker

my dev and I would like to implement the google picker on our website. It will allow the web-visitor to upload their files from their Google drive to our website.

My dev is now trying to get the API for the google picker however they are asking for a "demo video that showcases the process to request an OAuth token" and we were wondering how we should do it when we don't have the API from google.

We are doing all of this on the staging site and we were wondering how are we suppose to do this demo video when the API is not provided and not installed.

please enlighten us, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

See the question [How can I make sure the verification process is as streamlined as possible?](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#how-smooth) in the FAQ. It explains what the verification team is looking for with the video. Mostly it's just about showing how your product uses OAuth and the various APIs -- in your case how it asks for access to Drive, how the picker is used, etc. You're showing the integration from the user perspective.